# Referencing a global array from within a cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, global

I want to access the contents of a global array (450x9) from within a series of spreadsheet cells

I have tried everything I can think off the array is easy to fill from within a function but I cannot access it from within the cells

```
Option Explicit
Public calc_array (1 to 450, 1 to 9) as Double

Function fill_calc_array ( rowvar as Integer, var_1 as Double, var_2 as 
Double, var_3 as Double,........) as String

 calc_array(rowvar, 1) = var_1 * var_2 / var_3
 calc_array(rowvar, 1) = var_2 * var_3 / var_1
 calc_array(rowvar, 1) = var_3 * var_1 / var_2
 fill_calc_array = "Complete"

End Function
```

I want to be able to access the calc_array from within the VBA function but also be able to access the calc_array from within a specific cell, again like the following is what I would like to use:

Cell J5 is the month value between 1 and 450 , in cell K5 "=calc_array(j5,1)", L5 = "=calc_array(j5,2)", M5 = "=calc_array(j5,3)" etc

Try as I might I cant reference the global array variable from within a cell, so I wrote a function to access the array

```
Function access_global_array(rowvar as Integer, colvar as Integer) as Double
    access_global_array = calc_array(rowvar, colvar)
End Function
```

But this made the spreadsheet very slow (15 seconds to recalculate on a very fast machine).

I can fill the array but cannot access it from within a cell. The array exists in the VBA locals window but I cannot access it at all outside the debug screeens.

Comment: Since `Range.Value` is effectively yielding a 2D variant array for any multiple-cell `Range` address... why not populate an actual `Range` with the "global array" values, and use standard worksheet functions (`INDEX`, `MATCH`) to do these array lookups on worksheets? VBA code could still grab that range's `Value` and work with the array directly, and it could be exposed as a `Public Property Get` member on the worksheet that contains the data - it would still be global, but better modularized IMO.

Comment: What module is this `calc_array` declared in? If it's in a worksheet's code-behind modue, it's not global, but a public member of the worksheet module (e.g. `Sheet1.calc_array`). Declare global variables in a standard module.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify whether you're getting an error or not - "this made the spreadsheet very slow" means the UDF **can** access the array, and this directly contradicts the last sentence "I cannot access it at all outside the debug screeens". Make sure `Option Explicit` is specified at the top of every module, and confirm that the code still compiles.

Comment: `=calc_array(j5,1)` you cannot use this type of syntax to pull elements from a global VBA array - you must use the approach you ended up with  - a function which provides the access you need.  How/where are you calling `fill_calc_array` ?

Comment: If your function returns a 2D array to a worksheet cell, you should be able to access the individual elements using the `INDEX` function.